# looking for good geospatial library

Tags: gis, geospatial

What's a good library for geospatial functions?  I mean things like

- distance between two points on the globe
- coordinates of a circle of a given radius from a particular point
- etc.

Bonus if there's an interface to the various ways different databases
represent geolocations.

I'm a geo-noob (in case this question didn't make it obvious), so pointers to other geolocation/geospatial resources are welcome.

C++ and Python preferred, but all pointers welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've enjoyed using [geopy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy). It's a simple library that finds great-circle distance in a number of projections. Geopy also provides a single interface to multiple geocoders like Google Maps and Microsoft Earth to give you coordinates for a street address.

You might be interested in the [Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=391) section in PyPi.

Comment: This seems to be 3 years old. Did Google Maps have geocoding back then?

Comment: geopy can do screen scraping as an alternative to official geocoding APIs, but it works fine with Google's (and Yahoo,and MS, and ...) real geocoding API, too.

Comment: okay, this is awesome. like python always is. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Some options for functions from [a useful article](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2005/06/10/osgeospatial.html) on the O'Reilly website. There are other options in the article.

1. [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) open source C++ geometry /
   topology engine. Might suit you?
2. [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) - a PostgreSQL database
   that can also store geometric
   (spatial) data types. This provides
   GIS-like abilities within an SQL
   database environment, so you could do manipulations through SQL.

I'm not sure about interfaces to different databases but the article mentions a number of libraries that convert geospatial data between different formats. You might also be interested in the [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) standards. If all your target databases support [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) you should be able to access them with exactly the same code. EDIT: Increasing numbers of GIS packages support WFS but I don't think pure databases do.

EDIT: you could also check out [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/) which is a collaboration to support open source geospatial stuff. [FDO](http://fdo.osgeo.org/) might do the interfaces to different databases.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using ruby with or without rails, I'd recommend the GeoKit gem: http://geokit.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 2):

Check [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/) which is two libraries in one - [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) for raster data and [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) for vector data. The OGR part provides API to manipulate geometries - it uses [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at something similar, there's the [Geolocator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geolocator/0.1.1) Library that I found, it provides some distance calculation functions.